# JS to Regex user input box before submission

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Maybe I am going about this wrong.
But I have a username box. This format box can take either an email, or a phone number that is formatted like +1XXXXXXXXXX

No person is ever going to type a phone number like that.

So I a JS file to check the input box from azure B2C and change the format to remove any ( ) and - and prepend the +1 during submissions.

So if a user types XXX-XXX-XXXX it still works or if they type (XXX) XXX -XXXX or even XXXXXXXXXX. The submission goes out as +1XXXXXXXXXX. But it also needs to be able to handle an email address.

So this is the Azure B2C generated Form.

```
<input id="signInName" class="textInput" type="text" placeholder="Email address or phone number" aria-label="Email address or phone number" aria-required="true" autofocus="autofocus">
```

and this is the JS i have come up with so far.

```
const signInNameInput = document.getElementById('signInName');

const formatPhoneNumber = (phoneNumber) => {
  const formattedValue = phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '');
  return `+1${formattedValue}`;
}

const isEmail = (value) => {
  return /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(value);
}

const isPhone = (value) => {
  return /^\d{10}$/.test(value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
}

signInNameInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const value = signInNameInput.value;

  if (isPhone(value)) {
    signInNameInput.dataset.value = formatPhoneNumber(value);
  } else {
    signInNameInput.dataset.value = value;
  }
});

document.getElementById('attributeVerification').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const value = signInNameInput.dataset.value;
  
  if (isEmail(value)) {
    signInNameInput.value = value;
    event.target.submit();
  } else if (isPhone(value)) {
    signInNameInput.value = formatPhoneNumber(value);
    event.target.submit();
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid input');
  }
});
```

When i submit this form the format shows in the input box as XXXXXXXXXX and it fails, but when the page loads it shows +1XXXXXXXXXX and then i resubmit and it works.

i cant figure out how to get it to work BEFORE submission.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past by using Javascript's `onChange` event for that input.